# Show that $a \lt \frac{a + b}{2} \lt b$ for $a\lt b $ and $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How can I prove this statement true?

I have tried saying starting like this:

$a = 0; \qquad b>0.$

But I don't know where to proceed from here

Comment: from x<y you know x/2 < y/2. Then ad x/2 to both sides. Similarly add y/2.

Answer (score 8):

$$
a < b
$$

Add $a$ on both sides on the one hand, and also $b$ on the other hand:

$$
2a < a+b
\\
a+b < 2b
$$
this gives you 
$$
2a < a+b < 2b
\\\implies a<\frac{a+b}2<b
$$

Answer (score 4):

Since $a < b$, we have
$$a = \frac{a}{2} + \frac{a}{2} < \frac{a}{2} + \frac{b}{2} < \frac{b}{2} + \frac{b}{2} = b.$$

Answer (score 2):

Multiply by 2:
$$a<(a+b)/2<b\iff 2a<a+b<2b$$
Now you should clearly see that $2a<a+b\iff a<b\iff a+b<2b$.